# Create new data frame based on another data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this data frame DF1

```
emp_no  no_children  status
  1      3            3
  2      2            2
  23     5            5
```

And another DF2

```
emp_no  no_children  status
      1      3            3
      2      2            2
      3      5            5
```

I am trying to create a new dataframe based on DF1 and DF2 e.g

```
emp_no no_children status
  23     5         5
```

the new DF should contain emp_no not in DF2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) of the `emp_no` column and using the slice of `df1` dataframe.

```
df1.loc[df1['emp_no'].ne(df2['emp_no']),:]

  emp_no    no_children status
2     23              5      5
```

Comment: This would be tricky, if order of emp_no is different, and assuming emp_no is unique.

Comment: @Zero Can you explain with an example I didn't understand?. Also I wrote this solution after edit which explains `emp_no` of df should not contain `emp_no` of `df2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` with `how='left'` and `indicator=True` and then filter rows present in `df1`.

```
In [277]: df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='left'
              ).query('_merge == "left_only"'
              ).drop('_merge', 1)
Out[277]:
   emp_no  no_children  status
2      23            5       5
```

---

Details

```
In [278]: df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='left')
Out[278]:
   emp_no  no_children  status     _merge
0       1            3       3       both
1       2            2       2       both
2      23            5       5  left_only

In [279]: df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='left').query('_merge == "left_only"')
Out[279]:
   emp_no  no_children  status     _merge
2      23            5       5  left_only
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give df1 rows where df1['emp_no'] can't be found (~ is the negative) in df2['emp_no']:

```
df1.loc[~df1['emp_no'].isin(df2['emp_no'])]
```